# how to print the optimal number of clusters using fviz_nbclust

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, factoextra

I need a help to know how to find the optimal number of number of clusters using k-means cluster in R.

My code is

```
library(cluster)
library(factoextra)


#read data
data<-read.csv("..\file.txt",header=FALSE, sep=" ")

#determine number of clusters to use
k.max<- 22
wss <- sapply(2:k.max, function(k){kmeans(data, k, nstart=10 )$tot.withinss})

print(wss)

plot(2:k.max, wss, type="b", pch = 19,  xlab="Number of clusters K", ylab="Total within-clusters sum of squares")


fviz_nbclust(data, kmeans, method = "wss") + geom_vline(xintercept = 3, linetype = 2)
```

I get the plot, but I still do not know how to find the number?

Thanks

[My plot is in this link to show the rlation between wss and number of clusters with no information about the optimal number of clusters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tda3E.png)[image]

Comment: I tried to apply the code in http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/print.php?id=239#r-codes

Answer (score 4):

```
n_clust<-fviz_nbclust(df, kmeans, method = "silhouette",k.max = 30)
n_clust<-n_clust$data
max_cluster<-as.numeric(n_clust$clusters[which.max(n_clust$y)])
```

Comment: You should add a description to your answer to improve it.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

There is no sound mathematical definition of the "elbow" (because of having different scales on x and y, there is no angle), and in plots like yours there probably is no "elbow" at all.

Most likely, k-means did not work for any k. This happens quite often. For example if your data doesn't contain clusters.

Try generating uniform data, and do the same plot - it will look similar.

Comment: so do you think using k-means will not end up by having meaningful clusters?

Comment: Not if the curve looks like this. Plot 5000/k as comparison.